# Java abstract class function generic Type

Tags: java, class, polymorphism, gson, abstract

I created abstract class for my `ArrayList` holders

```
public abstract class ArrayHolder {
    Gson g = new Gson();
}
```

used like

```
public class MyHolder extends ArrayHolder {
    ArrayList<MyType> myList = new ArrayList<MyType>();
}
```

I would like to create abstract function to fill this `ArrayList` from `String` and `Type` argument

like this (`String data` is JSON in `String`) : **This function should be rewritten**

```
public ArrayList<T> arrayType(String data, T type){
    return g.fromJson(data, new TypeToken<ArrayList<type>(){}.getType());
}
```

to use it in subclass

```
public void fillData(String data){
    myList = arrayType(data, MyType.class);
}
```

How can I do this properly?

Thanks

Comment: So if I understand this right: you have a superclass C and you want it to fill an ArrayList in a subclass D through and abstract method in C?

Comment: @RyanAmos right. But not fill directly, just return ArrayList of right type

Comment: ah, well just use T. new ArrayList<T>. You don't need the T type parameter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this...

```
public abstract class ArrayHolder {
    Gson g = new Gson();

    public <T> ArrayList<T> arrayType(String data){
        return g.fromJson(data, TypeToken.get(new ArrayList<T>().getClass()));
    }
}
```

use

```
public class MyCollection extends ArrayHolder {
    private ArrayList<MyType> collection;

    public void setData(String data){
        collection = arrayType(data);
    }
}
```

Comment: Both codes throw an error `method getType() is undeclared for type ArrayList<T>`

Comment: I see, please answer below on @RyanAmos answer, why is TypeToken via inner class bad?

Comment: NP, notice that you don't need to pass the type as a parameter to your method. I forgot to remove it.

Comment: You got it. That's exactly How I needed it :)

Comment: Added example use to your answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
public <T> ArrayList<T> arrayType(String data){
    return g.fromJson(data, new TypeToken<ArrayList<T>>(){}.getType());
}
```

Comment: Your answer is closest to solution, I changed type to ArrayList from List and added missing Bracket.

Answer (score 2):

Do it like this:

```
public <T> ArrayList<T> arrayType(String data){
     return g.fromJson(data, new TypeToken<ArrayList<T>>(){}.getType());
}
```

I haven't dealt with generic typed methods, but from what I've seen, this is right.

Comment: `TypeToken` should not be created using an anonymous inner class but by using `TypeToken.get(...)`

Comment: @JohnB what is bad on creating TypeToken via inner class?

Comment: You don't know what non-public abstract methods Google needs in the implementation. They made the class abstract and hid the actual implementation class as a data-hiding mechanism. That is why they provide the `get` method to retrieve a concrete instance.